# How to set the PATH of glassfish-4 on mac

Tags: java, macos, glassfish

I have downloaded Glassfish 4 and unzipped it on Mac.

However, when I trying to start it with

```
../glassfish4/glassfish/bin asadmin start-domain domain1
```

the terminal says `-bash:asadmin start-domain domain1`

I have searched for solutions to solve this problem, but I am not sure how to set the PATH on `.bach_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your command is a little wrong. Try this:

```
../glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1
```

For more details including setting up the path see [this tutorial](https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-41-on-ubuntu).